# некорректно отображается кириллический символ Р (эр) в контролах Winform в mono под linux

Tags: linux, winforms, кириллица, mono

Есть проект на C#, портированный под linux (fedora, 32 bit).
Для UI используется WinForms.
Проект cкомпилирован на linux c пом. MonoDevelop.
Столкнулся со странным поведением отображением русской Р(верхний регистр) в текстовых контролах.

Странность заключается в следующем:
- не отображается глиф этого символа, если Р последняя (не единственная) буква в тексте (например, в текстбоксе,комбобоксе, метке... )
- если после последней Р ввести ещё символы, то она становится видимой.

Баг не проявляется при использовании GTK#.
Баг проявляется при использовании WinForms на Centos.

Подозрение падает на библиотеку winforms для mono - баг при рендеринге.

Вопросы:
- кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?
- каковы возможные варианты лечения?

Comment: Интересный вопрос, но будет нагляднее если Вы добавите минимальный пример кода и картинок.

Comment: Код самый примитивный - текстбокс на форме. В него вводится текст - дальше начинаются траблы с Р. Попробую создать скриншоты, но они мало чего добавят к пониманию проблемы.

Comment: Кодировка, наверное, CP1251. Если так, сделайте всё через UTF-8 или UTF-16.

Comment: @0andriy Кодировку в C# особо не поменяешь - это UTF16. Но с кодовыми страницами компилятора играть пробовал. Cтавил UTF8,16, IBM866, Win 1251 - не помогает. Похоже, и не д.б. помочь - это настройки кодировок файлов исходников.

Answer (score 2):

В какой-то степени решился вопрос
Принцип решения основывается на том, что в конец строки, содержащей последний неотображаемый символ Р, добавляется символ U+FEFF (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index), после чего проблема с рендерингом символа Р исчезает (он становится видимым).
Называется он примерно так - "пробел нулевой ширины".
После этого имплементация стала делом техники:

1. Создан контрол, отнаследованный от TextBox, в котором переопределен делегат TextChanged. В этом делегате и отслеживается добавление/удаление символа U+FEFF в конце текстовой строки;

2. Написана ф-ция, добавляющая  символ U+FEFF в строки, отображаемые иными контролами (combobox, listview,...)

После этого моя проблема  была решена полностью, а в сам баг в WinForms частично купирован.
Почему частично? Дело в том, что этот подход работал только со шрифтом Sans Serif (VS использует его по дефолту). При использовании другого шрифта такое решение может не позволить купировать этот трабл.  Для меня это ограничение оказалось некритичным - нужно только следить, чтобы в формах не появился проблемный шрифт.